# Creating and ajusting a UIButton within a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I want to create a button (not dynamically) bellow the last row in the table. All the rows and sections are fixed. Do I have to create another section and row just to add a button? and if yes how can I ajust the button to the same width and curvature of the cell?

Here is what I did. I create a specific section for the button and one row for it.

```
}else if(indexPath.section ==2)
    {
        UIButton *cellButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [cellButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 5.0f, cell.frame.size.width, 44.0f)]; // not filling the round parts of the cell
        [cellButton setBackgroundColor: [UIColor yellowColor]];
        [cellButton setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellButton];
    }

    return cell;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. Set your button as the table footer view of your table view.

```
tableView.tableFooterView = myButton;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. However, how can I adjust the size of the button for the same size of the cell. I've changed the type of my button and it only appears the title not the backgroundColor.

Comment: The default cell size is 44 pixel. Assuming iPhone: `button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);`

Comment: but there is one problem. If I set the button as custom style, the color change but there is no round corners. Whereas if I set the button style as rect the color stay behind(hidden) the button

Comment: Hhowever, you can `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` then set `button.layer.cornerRadius = 7.5;`

Comment: In my question I asked about width and curvature. Is there anyway to do this in the IB?

Comment: @Camus certainly. But why doesn't my previous comment suffice?

Comment: Your solution works. Thanks but I think a more graphically solution would be loading images for the buttons. What do you reckon?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14666/discussion-between-h2co3-and-camus)